# Array issue for String with variable length (variable-sized object may not be initialized)

Tags: c, string, initialization, arguments

I'd like to use the argument count in the command line to create a loop asking for user input of different names, depending on the length of argc. Each iteration should ask for new input which should be stored in an array of the variable 'results' like this:

results[3] = {"Brian", "Bob", "Sarah"}.

I'd like to use a for loop for it but I always get the "variable-sized object may not be initialized" error and I can't figure out what the issue is. Any ideas why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {

        string results[i] = get_string("Vote: ");

    }

}
```

The over all goal is to get command line input of n names and then ask

Comment: `string` is not part of the C language. Check by reading [this C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Your code won't even compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), which you should use as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Assuming you left out the CS50.h and that `string` is `char*` you redefine the array of pointers in  each loop. Which element will receive the function value? You need `string results[argc]` before the loop, and in the loop have `results[i] = get_string("Vote: ");` although I don't get the relevance of using `argc` from the example code.

Comment: Thank you so much @WeatherVane that actually solved the issue! You were right I forgot to include the <cs50.h> and <string.h> library in this example. Apologies.

However, when I move the declaration before the loop, that does the trick. And looking at it now, it makes total sense. Thanks!